# How can I convert this to an actual date?

Tags: backup, timestamp, acronis-trueimage

I recently did a backup with Acronis and saved the log. It turns out to be an xml containing some lines like this

```
<event code="504" id="5" level="2" message="Pending operation 158 started:'Creating partition image'." module="1" time="1450636575" />
```

Now, how in the world do I read that timestamp? Maybe its some absolute value since the computer got turned on, but probably they turned it on on the factory to test it so...?

Comment: That's pretty exactly 46 years, in seconds (I doubt your computer is that old), which gives us around Christmas 1969 as start point. Ringing any bells?

Comment: Something tells me Acronis did not exist back then. Some particular reason this was downvoted, do you think?

Comment: I can only guess - you did not seriously try to find out. It took me 20 seconds to calculate the start date, and it is common (Google) knowledge that all Unix clocks start at that date. It is expected that you try some research before you ask.

Comment: OK, sorry, I did google, so I just failed at it :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is a [unix timestamp](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unix_time). The clock is seconds from a particular date (starts at 1/1/1970).

Here is a converter:

http://www.onlineconversion.com/unix_time.htm

Your time is:

Sun, 20 Dec 2015 18:36:15 GMT

Comment: Thanks for this, I cannot explain how my google-fu was insufficient for this task.